# Term for a trainer who conducts training by outer standard programs

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word in English for a person who conducts trainings with a use of some already written programs?

It's not about program made by him - he just realizes outer standard programs.
And it's also not about qualification or junior role. It could be a very professional person.
In Russian, there is word "ведущий" for such meaning. But in this particular connotation it does not mean neither: presenter, principal, anchorman, master, narrator, etc. It is close to "conducting" - a person who conducts trainings or conductor of trainings.
But if I google "conductor of trainings" I would not find many examples of such phraseme.

Update:

1) It could be "Conductor of training" - it seems to be ok unlike "Conductor of training**s**"

2) It could be "Training facilitator" but I am not sure about it. Thanks to [Graffito](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/132252/graffito)

3) And yes, I do try to differentiate between "Training Program Developer" and "Trainer". Thanks to [Jim](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17956/jim). And I'd like to show that both roles were taken. At the same time context implies that "Trainer" is also "Training Program Developer" so I should find some options.

Comment: If the person is actually doing the training, consider *instructor*. If the person is just guiding people through a self-directed system, consider *mentor* or *proctor*. A *docent* could probably be used, or more informally, *shepherd*.

Comment: Nice, but I need to show some differencies on the way. Like: "assistant trainer, conductor of trainings, trainer". And this activity means training some skills, it's not only about knowledge.

Comment: _Instructor_ sounds good, but people need to get their own experience.

Comment: "Training facilitator" ?

Comment: Maybe 'Guide', or 'Course Leader' - both suggest that the person is taking their students along  a predetermined path, probably not of their own making.

Comment: If you are trying to differentiate between a "Course Content Developer" and a "Lecturer" or "Trainer" then use those terms acknowledging that some people are both.

Comment: Well, thanks to all. I should notice that I am not very proficient in English, so I am not completely sure about right answer :) 
It could be _"Training facilitator"_, but it is definitely not _Facilitator_.
It is neither  _Guide_, _Course Leader_ as it is not about course but about gaining experience and skills.
And yes, I do try to differentiate between "Training Program Developer" and "Trainer". And I'd like to show that both roles were taken. At the same time it is implies that "Trainer" is also "Training Program Developer" so I should find some options.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that answer would be "conductor of training" but not "conductor of training**s**". But I'm not sure.